# Scala: Forward reference errors during type pattern matching

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, forward-reference

I'm looking to understand the compile-time errors generated by the following Scala code:

```
class MyClass {
    def determineType(x:Any):String = {
        x match {
            case Int => "It's an int."
            case Float => "It's a Float."
            case CIn  => "It's a CIn without a specifier."
            case c:CIn => "It's a CIn with a specifier."
            case DIn=> "It's a DIn without a specifier." // Error:Cannot resolve symbol DIn
            case d:DIn=> "It's a DIn with a specifier."
            case _ => "It's something else."
        }
    }
    case class CIn()
    class DIn
} // End class definition

def determineType(x:Any):String = {
    x match {
        case Int => "It's an int"
        case Float => "It's a Float"
        case COut  => "It's a COut without a specifier." // Error: Wrong forward reference
        case c:COut => "It's a COut with a specifier."
        case DOut=> "It's a DOut without a specifier." // Error: Cannot resolve symbol DOut.
        case d:DOut=> "It's a DOut with a specifier."
        case _ => "It's something else."
    }
}

case class COut()
class DOut()
```

In the version of `determineType`within `MyClass`, both the `case class` `CIn` as well as the regular `class DIn` are defined and declared after `determineType`. A symbol resolution error is generated when trying to match against a `DIn` without a specifier variable.

At script scope, we similarly define a `case class` `Cout` and a regular `class` `DOut`. In the script-scope version of `determineType` we have two different errors. The first one is generated when referring to a `case class` type (`Cout`) without a specifier, and it reads "Wrong forward reference". The second one is generated when referring to a regular `class` type (`DOut`) without a specifier, and it is a symbol resolution error.

I'm new to the language and am thus not sure why the inclusion of specifiers in the `case` statements affects the way that forward references are treated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your write a match clause `case Foo =>` you are not matching for a *type* (or class) `Foo` but a *value* `Foo`. So `case Int =>` does *not* match for an integer value, and `case DIn =>` does not work because there is no value (or object) `DIn`.

The following works:

```
val Foo = 1
object Bar

def testVal(x: Any) = x match {
  case Foo => "it's Foo"
  case Bar => "it's Bar"
  case _   => "none of the above"
}

testVal(1)  // Foo!
testVal(Bar) // Bar
testVal(Foo + 1) // none
```

If you want to match for the instance of a class instead, you need to match for a clause `case b: Baz =>` or `case _: Baz` (if you are not interested in binding the instance to a value). For case classes, you can further more use the automatically provided extractor, so with `case class Baz()` you can also match as `case Baz() =>`. This usually makes more sense when `Baz` contains arguments which are hereby extracted:

```
case class Baz(i: Int)

def testType(x: Any) = x match {
  case Baz(3) => "Baz with argument 3"
  case b: Baz => "Baz with argument other than 3"
  case Baz    => "Baz companion!"
  case _      => "none of the above"
}

testType(Baz)     // companion object!
testType(Baz(3))
testType(Baz(4))
```

A case class also gives you a companion `object` so here you could actually match for that object using `case Baz =>`. An `object` is a kind of value.

---

Finally, I don't know which Scala version you are using, but in regular current Scala, you cannot omit the `match` keyword on the RHS of your definition of `determineType`:

```
def determineType(x: Any): String = {
  case _ => "anything"
}
```

> ```
> <console>:53: error: missing parameter type for expanded function
> The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
> Expected type was: String
>           def determineType(x: Any): String = {
>                                               ^
> ```

You have to write:

```
def determineType(x: Any): String = x match /* ! */ {
  case _ => "anything"
}
```

Comment: Amazing response, thanks. On your last comment, I actually edited the post to include the "match" keyword. Since there were compile-time errors showing up on the aforementioned lines of IntelliJ, I did not even run the script to have it complain for the missing keyword, and focused on the ones showing up.